# Triple Nested Attribute Forms in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have seen a few things about triple nested routes but cannot figure it out on the form level. I have everything else working it seems like including views, just not the form. So what I am attempting to do is create a rails app where I can add Group>Classification>Item

I have setup the models for has_many and belongs_to. I followed: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-nested-resources-for-a-ruby-on-rails-application

On how to setup a nested form. I got two levels working perfectly. Once I get to the third I can view the index but I cannot add. I have a feeling its either my controller or my form_with model. I have tried both:

```
<%= form_with(model: [@group, @classification, item], local: true) do |form| %>
<%= form_with(model: [@classification, item], local: true) do |form| %>
```

In the controller for the Item I have

```
before_action :get_group_classification

Private
def get_group_classification
   @classification= Classification.find(params[:classification_id])
end
```

Routes are setup like

```
  resources :groups do
    resources :classifications do
      resources :items
        end
  end
```

Any thoughts would be appreciated. I don't want to go any deeper than 3 tiers, but can't tell if that's bad protocol.

Answer (score 0):

In parent model:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :add_on_slider
  has_many :classifications, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :classifications, allow_destroy: true, :reject_if => :all_blank
end
```

In parent controller :

```
 def grouo_params
    params.require(:group).permit(:attribute name1, :attribute name2, :sub_title, classifications_attributes: [:id, :main_point, :_destroy, :important_id ,items_attributes: [:id, :attribute, :_destroy, :important_id]])
 end
```

In the view page:
You can use gem 'cocon'. You can see any tutorial related to it.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=56xjUOAAZY8

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly do it that way, the question is if you have any additional benefit of nesting routes so deeply. The main use case I've seen in the past where this was worth it was where authorization was handled by a parent attribute (in your case, if the authorization for an item was handled through the group).

A simpler way where you don't have to get so involved with routing so much is to pass `group_id` and `classification_id` as parameters in the form (e.g. as `hidden_field_tag`).

In the end, it's up to what you're trying to achieve and what other constraints you might have that are not evident from the bit of code that you've posted.

Comment: I was thinking about that last night. However any suggestions on how to route that? Particularity through views. So if I am at the Group page and I select a group and going into that group I want several Classifications that I can add and edit that are specific to that group and then each Classification has Items that are specific to that Classification and overall Group. However some Items might be able to be assigned to other Classifications as well down the road. But I just want it visibly easy to navigate without confusing someone on how to use it.

Comment: This would be a use case for shallow routes (see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#shallow-nesting). With this, you'd have the `group_id` and `classification_id` in the URL so you have access to them and can inject them as hidden fields into the form.